# Why is the class number $h(-16)=1$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, discriminant

For an integer $d<0$, we defined the class number of $d$, denoted $h(d)$ as the number of reduced positive definite binary quadratic forms with discriminant $d.$ We quoted a theorem (Baker, Stark 1967) that the only integers $d$ such that $h(d)=1$ are $-3,-4,-7,-8,-11,-19,-43,-67,-163$ - the fundamental discriminants, and $-12,-16,-27,-28$ - not fundamental but still class number 1.

Aren't both $(1,0,4)$ and $(2,0,2)$ reduced +def BQFs with discriminant $-16$? We defined $(a,b,c)$ to be reduced if either $-a<b\leq a<c$ or $0\leq b\leq a=c.$

Comment: Seems to me you just omitted the *primitive* in the definition of $h(d)$, the $(2,0,2)$ does not correspond to a primitive form.

Comment: But we chose to count the number of pos def reduced BQFs for a very specific reason, namely because each such BQF was a canonical representative of its equivalence class. If we're only counting primitive such forms, then some pos def BQFs (e.g $(2,0,2)$) are not equivalent to any of those representatives - and then the result we had (and one I've just seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form#Reduction_and_class_numbersv)) about class number $h(d)$ being number of equivalence classes of BQFs with discriminant $d$, falls apart. Are you sure this is the proper defn?

Comment: That would not be an issue, if you start only with primitive forms you can still form classes and have reduced representative as well. This is the approach I've seen in several sources (e.g. in Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2+ny^2$), but it is true there are sources where the primitive property is not mentioned - I am not sure why. I'm not expert in this area so I will let others explain.

Comment: @Sil  yes, just primitive forms are counted.

Answer (score 1):

Example, my little program showing class group and Gauss duplicate of each form.  This shows us the principal genus, which is the squares in the group.

There are numerous imprimitive forms for this discriminant.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$ ./classGroup
Absolute value of discriminant? 
3600
Impr 2 0 450
Impr 3 0 300
Impr 5 0 180
Impr 6 0 150
Impr 10 0 90
Impr 12 0 75
Impr 15 0 60
Impr 18 0 50
Impr 20 0 45
Impr 30 0 30
Impr 4 4 226
Impr 12 12 78
Impr 18 12 52
Impr 24 12 39
Impr 26 12 36
Impr 20 20 50
Impr 25 20 40
Impr 34 32 34
Discr  -3600 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5^2  class  number  16

 all  
    3600:  < 1, 0, 900>    Square      3600:  < 1, 0, 900>
    3600:  < 4, 0, 225>    Square      3600:  < 1, 0, 900>
    3600:  < 8, -4, 113>    Square      3600:  < 4, 0, 225>
    3600:  < 8, 4, 113>    Square      3600:  < 4, 0, 225>
    3600:  < 9, -6, 101>    Square      3600:  < 9, 0, 100>
    3600:  < 9, 0, 100>    Square      3600:  < 1, 0, 900>
    3600:  < 9, 6, 101>    Square      3600:  < 9, 0, 100>
    3600:  < 13, -12, 72>    Square      3600:  < 25, 0, 36>
    3600:  < 13, 12, 72>    Square      3600:  < 25, 0, 36>
    3600:  < 17, -2, 53>    Square      3600:  < 4, 0, 225>
    3600:  < 17, 2, 53>    Square      3600:  < 4, 0, 225>
    3600:  < 25, -10, 37>    Square      3600:  < 25, 0, 36>
    3600:  < 25, 0, 36>    Square      3600:  < 1, 0, 900>
    3600:  < 25, 10, 37>    Square      3600:  < 25, 0, 36>
    3600:  < 29, -24, 36>    Square      3600:  < 9, 0, 100>
    3600:  < 29, 24, 36>    Square      3600:  < 9, 0, 100>

 squares  
    3600:  < 1, 0, 900>
    3600:  < 4, 0, 225>
    3600:  < 9, 0, 100>
    3600:  < 25, 0, 36>

 fourths  
    3600:  < 1, 0, 900>


Discriminant      -3600     h :   16     Squares :    4     Fourths :    1
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/Desktop/Cplusplus$
```